# Adding air drag to a golf ball trajectory equation

Tags: c#, mathematics, physics, projectile-physics

I'm developing a 2D golf game in VB.NET 2005, but I am stuck on how to implement air or wind drag that should affect the ball.

Already I have these equations for projectile:

- \$v_0\$ for the initial velocity of a golfball when hit or fired
- Vertical and horizontal components the velocity of the golfball:
  $$
  \begin{align}
  v_x &= v_0 cos(\theta) \\
  v_y &= v_0 sin(\theta) - gt*
  \end{align}
  $$
- Vertical and horizontal distance of golfball:
  $$
  \begin{align}
  x &= v_0cos(\theta)t \\
  y &= v_0sin(\theta) t - (0.5)gt^2
  \end{align}
  $$

How do I add air drag to this equation to properly affect the velocity of the golf ball? I don't have any idea how to do it, has anyone worked with similar equations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if there even exists a closed form for drag or wind, but it is quite easy to simulate in a step-wise fashion (like all the physics libraries do):

1. set your initial condition:

   $$ x, y, v_x, v_y \; (\text{for }t=0) $$
2. update position:

   $$
   x = x + (v_x \times dt) \\
   y = x + (v_y \times dt)
   $$

   (where dt is the time elapsed since the last update, aka delta time)
3. calculate these velocity helpers:

   $$
   \begin{align}
   v^2 &= (v_x)^2 + (v_y)^2 \\
   \lvert v \rvert &= \sqrt{v^2}
   \end{align}
   $$

   (where \$\lvert v \rvert\$ represents the length of \$v\$)
4. calculate drag force:

   $$ f_{drag} = c \times v^2 $$

   (where c is the coefficient of friction *small!*)
5. accumulate forces:

   $$
   \begin{align}
   f_x &= \left(-f_{drag} \times {v_x \over \lvert v \rvert}\right) \\
   f_y &= \left(-f_{drag} \times {v_y \over \lvert v \rvert}\right) + (-g \times mass)
   \end{align}
   $$

   (where \$mass\$ is the mass of your golf ball)
6. update velocity:

   $$
   v_x = v_x + f_x \times \frac{dt}{mass} \\
   v_y = v_y + f_y \times \frac{dt}{mass}
   $$

That's basically [Euler's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) for approximating those physics.

---

A bit more on how the simulation as requested in the comments:

- The initial condition \$(t = 0)\$ in your case is

$$
\begin{align}
x &= 0 \\
y &= 0 \\
v_x &= v_0 \times cos(\theta) \\
v_y &= v_0 \times sin(\theta)
\end{align}
$$

It's basically the same as in your basic trajectory formula where every occurrence of t is replaced by 0.

- The kinetic energy \$KE = 0.5m(V^2) \$ is valid for every \$t\$. See \$v^2\$ as in (3) above.
- The potential energy \$ PE = m \times g \times y \$ is also always valid.
- If you want to get the current \$(x,y)\$ for a given \$t_1\$, what you need to do is initialize the simulation for \$t = 0\$ and do small dt updates until \$t = t_1\$
- If you already calculated \$(x,y)\$ for a \$t_1\$ and you want to know their values for a \$t_2\$ where \$t_1 \lt t_2\$, all you need to do is calculating those small dt update steps from \$t_1\$ to \$t_2\$

### Pseudo-Code:

```
simulate(v0, theta, t1)
  dt = 0.1
  x = 0
  y = 0
  vx = v0 * cos(theta)
  vy = v0 * sin(theta)
  for (t = 0; t < t1; t += dt)
    x += vx * dt
    y += vy * dt
    v_squared = vx * vx + vy * vy
    v_length = sqrt(v_squared)
    f_drag = c * v_squared
    f_grav = g * mass
    f_x = (-f_drag * vx / v_length)
    f_y = (-f_drag * vy / v_length) + (-f_grav)
    v_x += f_x * dt / mass
    v_y += f_y * dt / mass
  end for
  return x, y
end simulate
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, i'll try it out an get back to you.

Comment: from these equations you provided, i'd like to get the current X & Y for a give time (t), should i replace my Vo with V_x and Vo with v_y? Also if i need to add the initial KE with which  the ball was fired, will this `KE=0.5*m*(V*V)` be valid?

Comment: @Smith I'll edit my answer to account for your questions

Comment: this is exactly what i did, and x is always negative, why?